# Login script using PDO extension not working

Tags: php, pdo

I am unsure if I am doing it properly but I just started working with PDO and I am not able to get my code to work. I continue to get the error "sorry could not connect" and I am unable to figure out what is wrong.

Included below is the code that I am using:

```
function doRun( $data )  
    { 
        try 
        {
            $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testData', 'root', 'root');
            $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

                $stmt = $db->prepare('  SELECT 
                                                username, pass 
                                        FROM    
                                                testTable
                                        WHERE
                                                username = :name
                                        AND     
                                                pass = :pass

                                    ');

                $stmt->bindParam(':name', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':pass', $pass, PDO::PARAM_STR);

                $stmt->execute();

                //$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $result = $stmt->fetchColumn();

                if($result == false)
                {
                    echo 'sorry could not connect';
                }
                else
                {
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $user;

                    echo 'logged in as' . $user;
                }

        } 
        catch (PDOException $e) 
        {
            echo "throw";
        }

        $db = NULL;
    }
```

Comment: What is the response you are getting? Anything in your error log?

Comment: i don;t get anything in my php_error log and nothing with the display errors ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT); i only get sorry could not connect

Comment: it is possible that your query is not returning anything. check your table

Comment: i have put my query in my PHPMyAdmin and it works over there. i get the rows back. i did a print_r on result and all i get in return is a blank array.

Comment: You can check the webservers error-log. For example in apache2 running on ubuntu in    /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: i work on a mac with MAMP and i checked the php_error log already it doesn;t warn me of something :) i think the mistake is within the query but i am not sure what it is exactly because i am new to PDO and OOP programming. i followed several tuts and my code looks the same as in the tutorials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would give you 0 rows as it seems that `$username` and `$pass` are not defined:

```
  $stmt->bindParam(':name', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':pass', $pass, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                            ^^^^^^^^^
```

You probably want some elements from `$data` variable you are feeding to the function as a username and password.

Later on you are using a variable `$user` that is undefined as well.

What does `$data` contain?

Comment: Thanks! that did the trick i defined them like this
$username = $_POST['name'];
$pass = $_POST['pass']; right above the try but is that the correct way?

Comment: @user1453253 Not really, you would normally do some processing on your `POST` variables (not strictly necessary) and you should definitely not store a plain-text password, you need to use a salted hash (you can find more information here on SO about that).

Comment: ah yeah i know i have to use hash password. but this is only for testing how PDO works. for the processing i use a FORM class with validation in it already so i don;t think i have to do that twice :)

Comment: @user1453253 In that case this is definitely the right way :-)

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you are "unable to connect", even though you are connecting but you're not finding a match, is because your user variables are not defined.

Try the following solution:

```
<?php

function doRun( $data )  
{ 
    $msg = '';
    $username = isset($_POST['name']);
    $pass = isset($_POST['pass']);

    try 
    {
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testData', 'root', 'root');
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $stmt = $db->prepare('
            select
                username
                ,pass 
            from   
                testTable
            where
                username = :name
                and pass = :pass
        ');
        $stmt->execute(array(':name' => $username, ':pass' => $pass);
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

        if(!empty($result)){
            $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
            $msg = "logged in as $user";        
        }else{
            $msg = "Unable to connect";
        }

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: $e";
    }

    echo $msg

    $db = NULL;
} 
?>
```